# Clarification on writing community wiki posts to fairly generic questions

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, community-wiki

Lately I've been writing self-answering community wiki posts to address common questions I see in the Stack Overflow community that require more in-depth answers than most people are willing to devote the time to explain.

An example of such a post is here:

[What is AJAX and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009206/what-is-ajax-and-how-does-it-work)

Now, in general I know that Stack Overflow frowns upon these generic type questions, but my assumption is that it's directed at users who ask "How do I build a website?" and expect someone to answer such a complicated question for them. In this case, I'm trying to create an in-depth response for people to point to, so they don't have to sit down and type a length response out.

Unfortunately there seems to be confusion on whether such in-depth questions are welcome, since it's a bit out of the norm. I could technically make a blog post on it, and direct people to that, but then at some point I feel it will get that "spamming my blog" look, and upset people.

The only alternative I could think of is if there were a specific Stack Exchange site, say guides.stackoverflow.com, that I could use to post there instead.

To conclude:

- Are such posts okay?
- If not, are people really going to get irritated if I make a post on my own blog and continually link to it?
- Should I propose a guides.stackoverflow.com on Area 51, or would it just fall apart with me being the only one that would contribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I know what is "blog post" - I thought SO is a wiki as well?

In that case why not modify existing question / answer to include all good content one has than to create another question with pretty much deals with same question.

- BLOG: [What is AJAX and how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009206/what-is-ajax-and-how-does-it-work)
- Prev Q1: [How does AJAX work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510011/how-does-ajax-work)
- Prev Q2: [How Does AJAX work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332447/how-does-ajax-work)

I'm not an expert - from a normal user perspective, I don't see any issue in linking my own blog in an answer. Till the time it is relevant and not just aggregation of other answers I should be ok. One drawback is, I won't be getting benefit of other so many intelligent users improving my answer.

I would prefer creating a community-wiki answer on existing question that asks exactly the same question. It would get up-voted eventually to be what I originally intent it to be. Just my thought though. Would be interesting to know what mods think.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't meant to be _that much_ of a wiki.  Completely taking over someone else's answer is not a good idea.  However, you could add your own answers to those questions.

Comment: @SLaks - I meant taking over the question (even then not completely changing the question) rather than answer, but to include another answer that aggregates all the good answers out there in form of a blog. I've updated my answer to be more clear.

Comment: I've decided to go this route honestly. I'll just do a blog and post relevant code if necessary. Seems to be the route that brings up less confusion.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with writing answers that link to your own blog; I've done it myself.  People get upset about that when you **only** post links to your blog, or if the links aren't very relevant.  (And, in one case, when the blog had horrific advertising)

In addition, writing blog posts will make your content more discoverable; once someone comes across one such post, it will be easier to find others.

Note that, unless the user is specifically asking for an overview or tutorial; posting an answer with **nothing but a link** is frowned upon; you should include at least the basics of what the page says.
However, in your case, this isn't so relevant, because you're writing overviews.

Comment: (I don't have an opinion about whether these belong on SO itself)